# How to minimize mutual information between a variable and a correlated sequence of variables?

Tags: information-theory, upper-lower-bounds, mutual-information

I'm working on a problem of minimizing mutual information between a variable and a correlated sequence of variables.
Formally, I have random variable $Y$ and a sequence of random variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$, and I want to minimize $I(Y; X_{i})$ for $i \in {1,2,...,n}$.

What I know is that $X_{i}$ are highly correlated, which means that $I(X_{i};X_{j})$ may be quite small, but there is no mathematical constraint to guarantee it.

I know that the most straightforward method should be minimize $I(X_{i}; Y)$ one by one, but I want to figure out if there exists simpler way to do this.

I tried to use the concavity property of entropy to find a upper bound, I have:
\begin{align}
I(\frac{\sum_{i}{X_{i}}}{n};Y) &= H(\frac{\sum_{i}{X_{i}}}{n}) - H(\frac{\sum_{i}{X_{i}}}{n}|Y) \\
&\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}H(X_{i}) - H(\frac{\sum_{i}{X_{i}}}{n}|Y).
\end{align}

But since the sign of $H(\frac{\sum_{i}{X_{i}}}{n}|Y)$ is negative, I cannot do anything further.

Does anyone have an idea of this problem ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't think I understand the question - what's variable and what's given? What are the constraints? What's the objective? Can you write this out as some concrete optimisation problem in terms of the random variables and mutual informations et c?

Comment: To explain a little - right now, you started out saying that the $X_i$s are all correlated (which suggests some fixed law), and $Y$ is given (which again suggests a fixed law), in which case $I(Y;X_i)$ is just fixed. You then proceeded to study the mutual information between $Y$ and a sample mean, and I have no clue what that has to do with $I(Y;X_i)$. So I'm super lost on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Hi, thank you for you comment. This problem is in a machine learning model, so $X_{i}$ and $Y$ are learned by the model, thus $I(Y; X_{i})$ is not fixed. Also, my objective is to minimize $\sum_{i}I(X_{i};Y)$. And actually I know an algorithm that can minimize a single MI term $I(X_{i};Y)$, so I can run this algorithm $n$ times to solve this problem. But I want to find some simpler method for example minimize an upper bound of $\sum_{i}I(X_{i};Y)$, that's why I'm trying to study the MI between $Y$ and a sample mean.

Comment: So is the model taking in some data $D$ (maybe noise), and generating $(X_1^n, Y)$?  Also, then there is some constraint here right? Because all you need to minimise $I(X_i, Y)$ without constraints is to choose $Y$ independent of $X_i$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I can minimize $I(X_{i}; Y)$ by running the MI minimization algorithm $n$ times, but I wonder if there exists a method so that I only need to run the algorithm $1$ time, e.g. minimizing $I(\frac{\sum_{i}X_{i}}{n}; Y)$ . But I cannot proof that minimizing $I(\frac{\sum_{i}X_{i}}{n}; Y)$ can make $I(X_{i}; Y)$ small at the same time.

Comment: But why do you need to run anything if you have no constraints? Why don't you just output $Y = 1$ deterministically (which would make $I(X_i;Y) = 0$ for all $i$ simultaneously, which is the smallest possible value).